# String.Format: join two value in one padding

Tags: c#, vb.net, join, format, padding

How can I do something like

```
string.Format("({{0}{1},10})", "ABC", "DEF) // (    ABCDEF)
string.Format("({{0} {1},10})", "ABC", "DEF) // (   ABC DEF)
```

[image: Example]

I have to solve tihs operation with format. And I do not have a chance to combine elsewhere.

So is not it possible to do something like.

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("({0,10})", "ABC" + " DEF"));
```

I cant use join or concat or  a + b methods

**Why i want only format pattern?**
Because of usage like this.

```
//Dummy metod for example
public static string applyFormat(String format, String values, Object object )
{
    member1 = reflect from object by named extracted string
    member2 = reflect from object by named extracted string 

   or members[]= exploded string

   return String.Format(format, member1, member2);
   or return String.Format(format, members);

}
```

Usage example

```
 Console.WriteLine(applyFormat("({ {0}{1},-10})", "Member1,Member2", object)); // "({ {0}{1},-10})": Reflect and Join Member1 and Member2 and apply padding joined value
```

Thanks

Comment: It is possible. What is your question?

Comment: sory my bad english. You can see on picture what i want.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can .

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("({0,10}{1})", "ABC", "DEF"));
```

Comment: +1 Not sure why that was down-voted, I think it answers the question perfectly.

Comment: Thanks but this is not. I updated my question. You can see on picture what i want.

Answer (score 0):

I know you need a `string.Format` solution, but if possible you can also try by using this:

```
string output = ("ABC" + "DEF").PadLeft(10);
```

or using `string.Format`:

```
string output = string.Format("{0,10}", string.join("", new string[] { "ABC", "DEF"}));
```

**EDIT:**

Try :

```
string format = 10 - ("ABC" + "DEF").Length;
string output = string.Format("{0," & format & "}{1}", "ABC", "DEF");
```

Comment: I should not use somethink else format. (padleft or join)

Comment: @Fatih, may I ask why ? Is it a requirement ? Also, can you pass "ABC" & "DEF" in an array or fixed two elements will be concatenated ?

Comment: Here 10 would be your total padding width.

Comment: Thanks for answer. The second option is closer to the solution. Bu requires alternate params. I'll think about how to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's possible to do exactly what you want using String.Format - at least not very easily.

You can achieve what you want using the following code. May not be ideal, but it works. (perhaps you can wrap it in a separate method to keep things more clean):

```
Console.WriteLine(
           string.Format("{0}{1})", "ABC", "DEF")
                 .PadLeft(9) // Pad with spaces until length is 9
                 .PadLeft(10, '(')); // Add last pad using '('
```

Answer (score 0):

Padding

> Padding can be used with strings. This can be expressed declaratively
>   in formatting strings. Padding indicates that you are inserting a
>   variable number of characters at the left or right of the string to
>   reach a specified length.

Instead of the PadLeft and PadRight methods, you can use the string.Format method with special substitutions.

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
    //
    // The constant formatting string.
    // ... It specifies the padding.
    // ... A negative number means to left-align.
    // ... A positive number means to right-align.
    //
    const string format = "{0,-10} {1,10}";
    //
    // Construct the strings.
    //
    string line1 = string.Format(format,
        100,
        5);
    string line2 = string.Format(format,
        "Carrot",
        "Giraffe");
    //
    // Write the formatted strings.
    //
    Console.WriteLine(line1);
    Console.WriteLine(line2);
    }
}

Output

100                 5
Carrot        Giraffe
```

**For declaring padding** inside a format string, use the comma character followed by the padding size. You can use a negative padding size to add padding to the right, which will left-align the text.

[String.Format](http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-format)